# Creating External Table in Azure SQL DW from Azure BLOB Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-synapse, polybase

I am creating a data source in Azure SQL DW in order to create external table using BLOB storage data but I am getting error while creating data source. I am new to this polybase environment so, please share your thought.

I am trying to call the data source in the external table code.

**External Table**

```
create external table [DBA].[TEST]
(
[type] varchar(3) COLLATE   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
)
with (LOCATION='https://test.blob.core.windows.net/BCP/',
DATA_SOURCE=TEST,
FILE_FORMAT=pipe_header,
REJECT_TYPE=VALUE,
REJECT_VALUE=0
)
```

I am not sure which KEY do I need to pass here as well. Either I need to use BLOB storage key or something else as well.

**Data Source**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE TEST  
WITH (   
TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,  
LOCATION = 'https://test.blob.core.windows.net/BCP/'
, CREDENTIAL = KEYS
)  
;
```

**Error Code**

```
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 3, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'BLOB_STORAGE'.

Incorrect syntax near 'BLOB_STORAGE'. Expecting CEDS_HADOOP, CEDS_RDBMS, CEDS_SHARDMAPMANAGER, or CEDS_SHAREDMEMORY"
```

**Expectation**

I need to create external table in azure sql data warehouse using BLOB storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly `TYPE=BLOB_STORAGE` is not used in PolyBase, only in BULK INSERT/OPENROWSET from Azure SQL Database.  Use `TYPE=HADOOP`, as in this walkthrough: [Load Contoso Retail data to Azure SQL Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-blob-storage-with-polybase)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage
WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = 'wasbs://<blob_container_name>@<azure_storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential
);
```

Comment: Thanks @David Browne for your  response. I have a question here. Do I need to pass BLOB storage KEY1 in CREDENTIAL or which credentials I need to pas in CREDENTIAL parameter

Comment: You need to create a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL.  It's in that walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks and it makes sense.